# Automatic download file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, download

When user downloads the app & if there is any new content on the server (e.g. .xml file) then it will **automatically download** to the app, **Even if app is not open**

Does apple allow this kind of functionality?
If yes, then how can I implement this feature?

Help me to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean user just downloaded the app and not open and your application will start the downloading then its **Big NO.**

If you want to download the new contains then you have to do write code to check, validate and then download the data from server.

[image]

[image: Apple illustration for app state]

Comment: thanks but is there any trusted document for this to show to client?

Comment: look more details in apple doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html as application is not launched then it can not perform any operation like downloading new content.